# I want to turn to a specific page in a magazine

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, jquery-selectors

I'm using turn.js from github which is awesome.  They have one method that lets you turn to a specific page number:

```
$('selector').turn('page', pageNumber);
```

How do I make that work using an outside link.  For instance I click a link called "page #20" and it jumps to that specific page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#" id="page-#20"> Page 20 </a>

$('a[id^="page"]').click(function(){
  var thePage = $(this).prop('id').split('#');
  //$('select').turn('page', thePage[1]);
  console.log('The page is '+thePage[1]);
});
```